# is there any way to delete all data of table in sql database with C# (ms sql 14 management)

Tags: c#-4.0

i need some way to clear all data from all row in table using c#
//programme used to create data base is SQL Server 2014 Management Studio

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void delete(string table)
{
   try
   {
      using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Global.connectionString))
      {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM " + table, con))
        {
           command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        con.Close();
      }
  }
  catch (SystemException ex)
  {
      MessageBox.Show(string.Format("An error occurred: {0}", ex.Message));
  }
}
}
```